# Uploading Service Definition Failed

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, tiles, cache, publishing

Can anyone give me direction as to possible reasons why when publishing certain map services I get the "Packaging Succeeded but Publishing Failed" error?

When I expand the Geoprocessing Results window the failure is when trying to Upload/Publish the Service Definition file.  If I try to rerun the process from the .SD file I get an error message telling me that my .SD is not supported or doesn't exist; when I follow the path to the folder location my .SD is actually a .SDDRAFT.  If I change the file extension to .SD the process will run but it just fails like it did originally.

The frustrating part is that I have no problems publishing some things.  For example, a map service with only vector data publishes with no concerns, an image service with LiDAR in a GDB publishes without an issue, JPG rasters publish without issue how ever TIFF rasters are failing, any form of aerial imagery in a GDB is failing, TIFFs in a GDB are failing.  There seems to be no rhyme or reason to it as the same dataset will publish for one project but fail for another.

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic error but here is good [Esri Technical Support](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000016577) article on “ERROR 001369: Failed to create the service” that gives a clue into possible problems/solutions.

I would recommend you to go in the servers logs and try to identify the specific error report there.